# Why does the "d" key minimizes and restores the terminal?

Tags: 11.10, gnome-terminal, gnome-classic, keyboard-accelerators

I have a remote system on which I defined two accounts - an administrator and a standard user. The machine was fallbacked from Unity to GNOME. I use `vnc4server` to remotely connect to the system, and `RealVNC Viewer` for the actual connection from my Win 7 laptop.

From the two accounts I started the servers as:

`>> vnc4server -geometry 1440x900`

I also have the following `~/.vnc/xstartup` file in both accounts:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```

Now, when I connect to the admin account, I get a desktop and can open a terminal to type my commands.

On the user account, however, I can do the same - but when I type the <kbd>d</kbd> key, the terminal minimizes, until I press the key again. What's going on here? How can I claim my <kbd>d</kbd> back?

EDIT: thanks to [@zigg](https://askubuntu.com/a/115175/26972), I found the problem. I wonder, though, where does it inherited the "D" shortcut from? This is a fresh account and the changes I made were just to the .vnc file above???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the user account, check the Keyboard control panel, under Shortcuts.  "Minimize window" is set to "Disabled" on my system, but it may have accidentally been set to the letter d on your system.

If it is, you can hold down the mouse on that row until it says "New shortcut...", then press Backspace.

Comment: Yes, this led me to the problem! By default, I had just "D" in the "Navigation"->"Hide all normal windows" shortcut... changed it to Ctrl-Alt-D, like in the other account, and voila!

Comment: This worked for me too, but I had to log out and log back in before the changes were in effect.